# drm_kms_helper: panic occured, switching back to text console

Tags: usb, lubuntu

I've done a search for this issue but don't find a match to my particular set of circumstances. This is my first time trying to use Linux.

I have an Eee Pc Seashell series Asus netbook. I want to be able to play Minecraft on it and found some info on the net that suggested if I remove the Windows 7 OS and use Linux instead, that would leave enough resources on the computer to run Minecraft.

I downloaded Ubuntu onto a USB drive and inserted that drive into the netbook and rebooted. This successfully wiped out the Windows OS but did not install Ubuntu. Basically turned the computer into a paperweight. Oddly enough, it also corrupted the USB drive too and when I went to another computer to try to delete the Ubuntu off of it and try something else, the computer would only read it as a wifi adapter. So, I purchased a new USB drive and this time loaded Lubunto 14.04.1 onto it. I used Universal USB Installer 1.9.5.8 to put the Lubuntu download onto the new USB drive. I then inserted that drive into my netbook and turned the netbook on. At first it seemed like it would work but then I got a string of text that ended with the error in the Title of this post. It seems stuck there. This happened when I tried to run the installer or "try" the OS (I guess this is called using the Live mode from what I see in installation instructions.)

Because the computer has no OS, I'm not seeing how I can try the other solutions to this error I've seen. Anyone have any solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your PC has an Intel Atom processor and only 1GB of RAM, so Lubuntu was the right choice, but *some of the Intel atom processors do not support PAE*.

So follow the official [Ubuntu PAE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE) instructions and if that fails, you basically *do* have a pretty expensive doorstop.